# Are the "full size" images from Instagram on a browser actually full size?

Tags: google-chrome, resolution, image-processing, instagram

I am following the "view page source" method for getting the full resolution of an Instagram image, but feel like I'm doing something wrong. Let's consider this [example](https://www.instagram.com/wallpaper.4k.hd/p/Ci4SvJ1uai8/?hl=en).

If you view source in Chrome and get the one marked the highest, then download it, it becomes a 90kb jpg. Is anything being lost, or is the 90kb jpg essentially all that Instagram has after compressing upon upload? I notice that Instagram will store all images in jpg, is this correct?

Lastly, the images I want don't even have the multiple resolution options when I view source. The entre html looks like shown below. In that case, what resolution am I getting?

> <img alt="DESCRIPTION" crossorigin="anonymous" src="URL" class="CLASS ID" style="object-fit: cover;">

Comment: Internet pages are highly optimized. Why serve better quality and resolution than required? Even if I had the original resolution in store, I know I wouldn't serve it, ever.

Comment: @DanielB I agree with you, Instagram says they reduce quality to 1080x1920. I'm asking whether I can actually get the full 1080x1920 they promise.

Answer (score 2):

Instagram doesn't show the original pictures. Here's how to access them anyway.

From the article
[How to View Original Full-Size Pictures & Profile Photos on Instagram](https://www.alphr.com/view-original-full-size-instagram-pictures-profile-photos/).

In a nutshell, these pictures are not accessible from the Instagram
application, but can be accessed from the browser on a PC, this way:

- On the browser, open the picture you wish to download
- Modify the URL in the address bar by appending to it
  `media/?size=l` (lowercase L for large-size).
- Press Enter to execute the URL
- Save the image.

The modified URL might look something like:

```
https://www.instagram.com/p/B-KPJLlJ2iJ/media/?size=l
```

(I don't use Instagram so can't test this.)

Comment: Works great! For the example in the question, the URL needs to be edited down to exclude the name, like: `https://www.instagram.com/p/Ci4SvJ1uai8/media/?size=l`, and remains a 90KB image at 1080p

Comment: I've been doing that if there's one image. Doesn't work well on a multi-image post.